# Prevent UIStackView from compressing UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am adding a UITableView into vertical UIStackView. That vertical UIStackView is within a UIScrollView.

However the table is not displaying unless I force an explicit Height constraint on it which I obviously don't want to do.

According to this SO question and answer [UITableView not shown inside UIStackView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39481153/uitableview-not-shown-inside-uistackview) this is because "stackview tries to compress content as much as possible"

If I add a UILabel to the StackView it is displayed fine. There is something specific about the UITableView that means it is not. I am using Xamarin and creating the UITableView in code

```
this.recentlyOpenedPatientsTable = new UITableView()
{
    RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension,
    EstimatedRowHeight = 44.0f,
    AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = false,
    TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false,
    Editing = false,
    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear,
    TableFooterView = new UIView(),
    ScrollEnabled = false,
};
```

The UIScrollView is pinned to the Top, Bottom, Left and Right of the View and works fine. It takes the Height I expect.

I have tried both the suggestions in this SO question and neither have worked. I find it odd that I cannot find others having this issue.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use self sizing `UITableView` I explained it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56406813/5623035

Comment: A standard `UITableView` does not have an intrinsic height... you define its height, and it scrolls its rows within that height. If you want a table view arranged in a `UIStackView`, you have to either give it a height constraint, or make it non-scrollable and use an extension or subclass to ***give it*** an intrinsic height. Here is a simple example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56703886/6257435

Comment: Normally I rely on a combination of RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension and AutoLayout in the UITableViewCell. That's what I am trying in this instance and it is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a very basic example, using a `UITableView` subclass to make it auto-size its height based on its content.

The red buttons (in a horizontal stack view) are the first **arranged subView** in the vertical stack view.

The table is next (green background for the cells' contentView, yellow background for a multi-line label).

And the last arranged subView is a cyan background `UILabel`:

[image]

Note that the vertical stack view is constrained 40-pts from Top, Leading and Trailing, and ***at least*** 40-pts from the Bottom. If you add enough rows to the table to exceed the available height, you'll have to scroll to see the additional rows.

```
//
//  TableInStackViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 6/24/19.
//

import UIKit

final class ContentSizedTableView: UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIView.noIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }

}

class TableInStackCell: UITableViewCell {

    let theLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.textAlignment = .left
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        contentView.backgroundColor = .green

        contentView.addSubview(theLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            theLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            theLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.layoutMarginsGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            ])

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


}

class TableInStackViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let theStackView: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.axis = .vertical
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fill
        v.spacing = 8
        return v
    }()

    let addButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Add a Row", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let deleteButton: UIButton = {
        let v = UIButton()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.setTitle("Delete a Row", for: .normal)
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        return v
    }()

    let buttonsStack: UIStackView = {
        let v = UIStackView()
        v.axis = .horizontal
        v.alignment = .fill
        v.distribution = .fillEqually
        v.spacing = 20
        return v
    }()

    let theTable: ContentSizedTableView = {
        let v = ContentSizedTableView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v.textAlignment = .center
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        v.text = "This label is the last element in the stack view."
        // prevent label from being compressed when the table gets too tall
        v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        return v
    }()

    var theTableData: [String] = [
        "Content Sized Table View",
        "This row shows that the cell heights will auto-size, based on the cell content (multi-line label in this case).",
        "Here is the 3rd default row",
    ]

    var minRows = 1

    let reuseID = "TableInStackCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        minRows = theTableData.count

        view.addSubview(theStackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain stack view 40-pts from top, leading and trailing
            theStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            theStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // constrain stack view *at least* 40-pts from bottom
            theStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            ])

        buttonsStack.addArrangedSubview(addButton)
        buttonsStack.addArrangedSubview(deleteButton)

        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(buttonsStack)
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(theTable)
        theStackView.addArrangedSubview(bottomLabel)

        theTable.delegate = self
        theTable.dataSource = self

        theTable.register(TableInStackCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseID)

        addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addRow), for: .touchUpInside)
        deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRow), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    @objc func addRow() -> Void {
        // add a row to our data source
        let n = theTableData.count - minRows
        theTableData.append("Added Row: \(n + 1)")
        theTable.reloadData()
    }

    @objc func deleteRow() -> Void {
        // delete a row from our data source (keeping the original rows intact)
        let n = theTableData.count
        if n > minRows {
            theTableData.remove(at: n - 1)
            theTable.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return theTableData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID, for: indexPath) as! TableInStackCell
        cell.theLabel.text = theTableData[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: `contentSize.didSet` should at least check that value changed before invalidating layout. Calling `layoutIfNeeded` is not enough for `contentSize` to be calculated correctly. `layoutIfNeeded` will lay out cells in current frame but height of all other cells will be calculated using estimated height.

Comment: I haven't managed to get it working as yet. My use case is a bit more complicated with a number of StackView in StackViews. If I add a Label to the bottom of the StackView that label does display. It's just that TableView that is being compressed

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee - well, then you need to edit your question and explain exactly what you are trying to do. Tough to offer help / a solution if we don't know.

Comment: Updated. UIScrollView is more than likely a key piece of information that I didn't previously mention.

Comment: @PatLong-MunkiiYebee - well, the code you added to your question shows that you're using a default `UITableView`, which won't do what you want. You need to use the `ContentSizedTableView` as in my example code.

Comment: Once again you are correct and this is now working. Only change I needed to make because it was specific to my implementation was I am constraining to my outer UIStackView's LayoutMarginsGuide rather than it's (or the View's) safeAreaLayoutGuide. We are still supporting iOS10 so that explains why that didn't work